# Problem with Python 3 AES decryption, IV lenght problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, aes

i was trying to decrypt an AES ciphertext with Python 3.

I know that the key has been encoded as it follows (javascript) :

```
var k = CryptoJS.SHA256("\x93\x39\x02\x49\x83\x02\x82\xf3\x23\xf8\xd3\x13\x00"); 

    if(u == "\x68\x34\x63\x6b\x33\x72") {
        var enc = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(p, CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(k.toString().substring(0,32)), { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(k.toString().substring(32,64)) });
        if(enc == "PKhuCrfh3RUw4vie3OMa8z4kcww1i7198ly0Q4rpuyA=") {
            t = true;
        }
    }
```

Now, as you can see the IV of the encryption is 32 characters long, however in python 3 i can't use a string of length 32 as my IV.

I use the following code :

```
def decrypt(encrypted, passphrase_full):
  half1_passphrase = passphrase_full[0:32]
  half2_passphrase = passphrase_full[32:]
  print(len(half2_passphrase))
  IV = half2_passphrase
  aes = AES.new(half1_passphrase, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
  return aes.decrypt(encrypted)
```

And i get

> ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long

So, how can i decrypt my string correctly ?
Thank you very much

Comment: The IV has to be 16 bytes. [source](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/50782/what-size-of-initialization-vector-iv-is-needed-for-aes-encryption)

Comment: So, how can the javascript part work if the given string is 32 character long ?
{ iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(k.toString().substring(32,64)) }

Comment: The IV part of the JS code looks a bit like it decodes hex values. Two hex digits make one byte and 32 make 16.

Comment: The problem is that i've printed the value given by that function and it is long 32 character

Comment: Have you missed the `Hex.parse()`? 32 hex characters = 16 bytes.

Comment: So, please, tell me how to do the equivalent of Hex.parse() in my python code.
I have a 64 character long string, and i want to use the first half as key and the second half as IV

Comment: Either [`bytearray.fromhex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray.fromhex) or don't hex-encode your hash (use the `.digest()` method). Note that it's not a good idea to use part of the key as IV, the IV should be random. If you use the same key to encrypt multiple messages, they will have the same IV and that could leak some information about your message.

Comment: Yes , in fact i'm using this knowledge of how that IV  is made to crack the ciphertext  as a personal academic interest.